# basic node.js code not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, cloud9-ide

Server is starting without any errors but the URL is hit its showing no application running.

URL:<kbd>[link_To_Server](https://bong-c9-rajeshwar90.c9.io/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io)</kbd>

**My Code:**

```
var express= require('express');
 var app=express();

 app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('home');
  res.send(200);
  res.end('getting requests');
 });
 console.log('server started');
```

Comment: Is this your entire code? If so, you haven't called `app.listen(port);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't actually set the server to listen to a port. Replace

```
console.log('server started');
```

With

```
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('server started');
});
```

Note that with the above example, the bound port is 3000. For more info, see [the API doc](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.listen)

Comment: Please remember that port 3000 will not work in Cloud9 and you need to use $PORT. In Node.js you can use `process.env.PORT`. Same for `process.env.IP` or use 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Can you please drop a mail to me(ready.raj@gmail.com) so that I can stay in touch with you personally.As I am a new learner of node.js and angular.js can you please guide me.Thanks in advance.